# TYPO3: How can i create a custom page type url with typeNum=20 and reference that on the Controller

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

I created an empty function. And I have a xml file which has information inside. I want to send this file with Postman to this URL and save the information with my function. Anyone any ideas ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Hey there and welcome to StackOverflow.

I used to handle such a function recently and I did it this way:

- Create a page type in TypoScript to handle typenum (in your case 20)
- Listen to a special POST parameter (which you defined, e.g. `data`)
- Add your code what should happen with the data
- Send the information with POST and the XML via Postman to your.typo3.tld/?type=20

Comment: Hey Thanks for your Answer. I created now in Typoscript my Url. Is there any  way to map the URL to a function in Typo3? My Url is now working but i can not map the url to my function.

Answer (score 1):

Your TypoScript object will be like this

```
mycustompageType = PAGE
mycustompageType{
       typeNum = 1897
       config {
             #Required configuration
       }
       10 = USER_INT
       10{
         vendorName = YourVendorName
         userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
         extensionName = YourExtensionName
         pluginName = YourPluginName
         controller = YourController
         switchableControllerActions {
            YourController { 
              1 = YourAction
           }
        }
      }
   }
```

You can get extension detail using below code 
// get extension information

```
echo $this->request->getControllerExtensionName()."<br>"; 
echo $this->request->getPluginName()."<br>"; 
echo $this->request->getControllerName()."<br>";
```

Finally, you have to run this URL "yourdomain.com/?type=1897"

Enjoy!!